# Debate: Exclude - or not - characters from registration system? Safety?

Tags: regex, character, controls, registration

I build a simple website for a student web project and one of my friend ask me to **add a characters control on my registering system** like a regex (website built with PHP).

In fact, **I agree to exclude some characters** like *space*, *dot* or *@*, but why exlude **/**, ***** or **-** characters? (I speak here about *usernames* and *passwords fields*)

Some people say it's **for safety**, but in reality, **isn't the developers to implement a internal security code** to do that?

Question: **why people thinking this characters are dangerous**? We can use them on text fields like on *stackoverflow* for example, so what is the difference with *usernames* fields?

What's your opinion, do you use regex on your project to secure your entries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that it's because they can be used as comment delimiters which could make your code vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.
e.g.:

```
-- An SQL comment. Very dangerous if not handled properly
// C, JavaScript, PHP, etc. Not applicable to SQL
/* C, JavaScript, PHP, etc. */
```

**All** user input should be sanitised before using in a database. Regex is simply one tool that can be used, not necessarily the best one. Consider using a library that sanitises the input for you rather than building your own queries.

Personally, I'd allow all characters and make sure I'd sanitised them by trying to break my own code with injection attacks.

Comment: Currently, I use pdo to connect myself to my database. It's sufficient, or I need to add another protections (including Regex)?
While I am: what do you use in JEE/C#? The MySql connector is good enough?

Comment: As long as you're not inserting strings directly into the query but using PDO functions to do it you should be fine. You can try something like `SELECT * FROM <user_input>, "Safe!"`, use PDO to insert the user input into the query and then try `foobar -- injection attack!` to see what happens. If you get `Safe!` in the second column the injection attack failed.

Comment: The mysqli ("i" for "improved") connector (never use mysql anymore) can be made safe but it's a lot of hard work and easy to miss something. As for the other languages, I don't have direct experience with them but you could do the same test as above to see what happens.